# How to combine these two queries?

Tags: php, mysql

```
SELECT htpid AS parentid 
    FROM likehot WHERE htpid 
    IN (SELECT id FROM bultin WHERE  DATE  >= '1317108749') 
    GROUP BY htpid ORDER BY COUNT( htpid ) 
    DESC
```

giving result

```
parentid
16060
16059
16058
16057
```

and other query

```
SELECT app_id,bultin.id,photo_album_id,entcmmnt_id,link_url,youtubeLink,
       link_image,id, mem_id, subj, body, bultin.date,parentid, 
       from_id, visible_to, image_link,post_via 
FROM bultin 
WHERE id IN ('16062','16059','16058','16057') 
ORDER BY FIELD('16062','16059','16058','16057') 
LIMIT 5
```

Actually I wanted the same sequence as that of in IN so I used FIELD operator

Please Suggest 
thanks

Comment: @MarkByers,I wanted to make them run in single query..

Comment: Brave men run queries in a single one

Comment: @clinisbut,Do u guys have the ans plz..

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't Understand Your Question.. If You Can Please Explain it a better way.. I can gave you the Solution.. Wel I would like to say that u can not use more then one value in side the First Query "SELECT id FROM bultin WHERE  DATE  >= '1317108749')". And One more thing Y don't u use the values in the ist query like this

SELECT htpid AS parentid 
    FROM likehot WHERE htpid 
    IN (16062','16059','16058','16057')

Comment: Acually   `htpid IN (16062','16059','16058','16057')` is the result coming in first list.

Answer (score 0):

If I haven't miss anything, this should do the job:

```
SELECT b.app_id, b.id, b.photo_album_id, b.entcmmnt_id, b.link_url, b.youtubeLink,
    b.link_image, b.mem_id, b.subj, b.body, b.date, b.parentid,
    b.from_id, b.visible_to, b.image_link, b.post_via
FROM bultin AS b
JOIN (
    SELECT htpid, COUNT( htpid ) AS htpid_count
    FROM likehot
    GROUP BY htpid ORDER BY COUNT( htpid )
    DESC
) AS l ON l.htpid = b.id
WHERE DATE  >= '1317108749'
ORDER BY l.htpid_count
LIMIT 5
```

Let me know if you need more details about this query.

Comment: I think you should delete `ORDER BY COUNT( htpid )` from subquery.

Comment: The original was `GROUP BY htpid ORDER BY COUNT( htpid )`, that's why the optimized version I think should be ordered like this in subquery and also ordered afterward by l.htpid_count in the main query